# Open Image in default android image viewer

Tags: android, image

Im trying to make an app that uses the camera to capture the image.

the code for obtaining the bitmap is :

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
```

Now i want to view the image using the default image viewer of android without saving it to the internal or external storage.

How can i achieve that?

I tried launching `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` but that requires a uri arguement which i dont have as i am not saving the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i want to view the image using the default image viewer of android
>   without saving it to the internal or external storage.

Sory its not possible yet in android ,

for your app the image viewer is the third party app and  the third party apps can not use your object data directly .

better you can save you image in cache memory of your app if size of device storage  really does matter to you

**or**

you can save that image in device storage , view it using third party apps and delete it after that .

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use bellow code.

```
// open camera  
try {
    Intent action = new Intent(
            "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    action.putExtra(
            MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    .toString());
    startActivityForResult(action,
            TAKE_PICTURE_FROM_CAMERA);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// save image 

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

   iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: The question is about viewing image, not saving.